# Compass Application not working - Android eclipse

Tags: android

I am trying to build a compass application using android. My compass image is showing up but it is not moving. The headings on top and bottom of the compass should be displaying the direction the compass is showing, and the compass is supposed to move too. It was working fine but then I tried to create and independent public class for the compass and now I am stuck. Please help!

MainActivity.java :

```
package com.example.compass;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends Activity  {

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.compass_widget);
}

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff" >

<com.example.compass.CompassWidget
    android:id="@+id/compassWidget1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="148dp" >
</com.example.compass.CompassWidget>

</RelativeLayout>
```

CompassWidget.java :

```
package com.example.compass;

import com.example.compass.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.RotateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CompassWidget extends RelativeLayout implements SensorEventListener {



// define the display assembly compass picture
private ImageView pic;

// record the compass picture angle turned
private float currentDegree = 0f;

//device sensor manager
private SensorManager SensorManager;

private Context mContext;

private TextView compassHeading;

private TextView compassActualHeading;

private String direc = "";

private String oppDirec;




@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public CompassWidget(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mContext = context;

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.compass_widget, this);

    // our compass image 
    pic = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.compassImage);

    // TextView that will tell the user what degree is he heading
    compassHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.compassHeading);

    // TextView that will tell the user what degree is he actually heading
    compassActualHeading = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.compassActualHeading);

    // initialize your android device sensor capabilities
    SensorManager = (SensorManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

    SensorManager.registerListener(this, SensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),
            android.hardware.SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
}



@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    // get the angle around the z-axis rotated
    float degree = Math.round(event.values[0]);


    // East is 90, North is 0, NE is 45, West is 270, South is 180, SE is 135, SW is 225, NW is 315

    //opposites: north = south; east = west; northwest = southeast; northeast = southwest; 
    if (degree == 0) {
        direc = "N";
        oppDirec = "S";
    }
    else if (degree == 90) {
        direc = "E";
        oppDirec = "W";
    }
    else if (degree == 180) {
        direc = "S";
        oppDirec = "N";
    }
    else if (degree == 270) {
        direc = "W";
        oppDirec = "E";
    }
    else if (degree == 45) {
        direc = "NE";
        oppDirec = "SW";
    }
    else if (degree == 135) {
        direc = "SE";
        oppDirec = "NW";
    }
    else if (degree == 225) {
        direc = "SW";
        oppDirec = "NE";
    }
    else if (degree == 315) {
        direc = "NW";
        oppDirec = "SE";
    }
    else if (degree >= 0 && degree <= 22.5) {
        direc = "N";
        oppDirec = "S";
    }
    else if (degree >= 22.5 && degree <= 67.5) {
        direc = "NE";
        oppDirec = "SW";
    }
    else if (degree >= 67.5 && degree <= 112.5) {
        direc = "E";
        oppDirec = "W";
    }
    else if (degree >= 112.5 && degree <= 157.5) {
        direc = "SE";
        oppDirec = "NW";
    }
    else if (degree >= 157.5 && degree <= 202.5) {
        direc = "S";
        oppDirec = "N";
    }
    else if (degree >= 202.5 && degree <= 247.5) {
        direc = "SW";
        oppDirec = "NE";
    }
    else if (degree >= 247.5 && degree <= 292.5) {
        direc = "W";
        oppDirec = "E";
    }
    else if (degree >= 292.5 && degree <= 337.5) {
        direc = "NW";
        oppDirec = "SE";
    }
    else if (degree >= 337.5) {
        direc = "N";
        oppDirec = "S";
    }

    if (direc != null && oppDirec != null) {
        compassHeading.setText(direc);
        compassActualHeading.setText(oppDirec);
    }

    // create a rotation animation (reverse turn degree degrees)
    RotateAnimation ra = new RotateAnimation(
            currentDegree, 
            -degree,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, 
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
            0.5f);

    // how long the animation will take place
    ra.setDuration(210);

    // set the animation after the end of the reservation status
    ra.setFillAfter(true);

    // Start the animation
    pic.startAnimation(ra);
    currentDegree = -degree;

}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

compass_widget.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fff" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/compassHeading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/heading" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/compassImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/compassHeading"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/compass" />

 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/compassActualHeading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/compassImage"
    android:text="@string/heading2" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

This may sound silly but, are running it in the Android Emulator? Sounds like that.

If so, I'd have to point out that the emulator will not give you any sensor information. You should try your app in a real device (it is much more fun, also).